# Give the regular expression for the set of strings $\{a, b, c\}$ that do not contain substring $aa$

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

> Give the regular expression for the set of strings $\{a, b, c\}$ that do not contain substring $aa$.

How to solve this regular expression? I've been thinking for a long time to generalize that. But unfortunately, I couldn't.

What I've tried:

$(a(b \cup c))^{*}$ $\cup$ $(a (c \cup b))^{*}$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @manooooh Added.

Comment: The expression $b\cup c$ is the same as $c\cup b$ so you’ve written the same thing twice. In any case, I think you meant $\{b, c\}$.

Comment: Also, do you mean that $\{a, b, c\}$ is an *alphabet* as opposed to a set of *strings*? The latter would introduce issues, for example, if $b = a a$, so we would need more information.

Comment: There may be an easier way, but one way is to note that the complement of your set is easy to describe by a regular expression  (e.g., $(a|b|c){*}aa(a|b|c|){*}$) and you can convert that into a regular expression for your set, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685182/complement-of-a-regular-expression.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362133/example-of-language-that-does-not-contain-substring-11) should help you.